# What's going on when we expand std::vector<>?

Tags: c++, memory, vector, memory-management, stl

What happens when we do `push_back` with `size() == capacity()`?

I've heard a lot of opinions regarding this question. Most popular is: when the vector's size reaches its capacity, it allocates a new region of memory, copies the vector to the newly allocated memory, and inserts new value to the vector's end.

But, why do we have to do it? We have a virtual memory mechanism, we can just call `realloc(vec.data(), (sizeof(vec::value_type) * vec.size()) * 2)`. The `Allocator` will give us a new memory page, and virtual addresses make the memory "consistent", so we don`t have to copy values from the vector.

Do I understand the virtual memory mechanism wrong?

Comment: ***we can just call realloc(vec.data(), (sizeof(vec::value_type) * vec.size()) * 2)*** No we can't that would only work if there was nothing allocated in the memory locations to the right of the vector. Although realloc has a similar restriction anyways. "In the C Programming Language, the realloc function is used to resize a block of memory that was previously allocated. The realloc function allocates a block of memory (which be can make it larger or smaller in size than the original) and copies the contents of the old block to the new block of memory, if necessary."

Comment: `realloc` is nothing to do with VM anyway. If you want to interact directly with VM, you need something platform-specific like `mmap`. The `realloc` function can be implemented perfectly well on non-virtualized single-tasking machines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You understand virtual memory mechanism correctly, basically you can create any amount of **continuous page-aligned** arrays in the proces' virtual memory space and they would be backed by non-contiguous physical memory.

But that is irrelevant to `std::vector` because `std::allocator` does not provide any API to take advantage of that, I think some see this as an oversight.

Just be mindful that C++ is not restricted to only architectures supporting virtual memory, although I think it would be an implementation detail of the standard library if it were implemented anyway.

No, you cannot use C `realloc` because C++ has objects with real lifetimes, everything is not just a blob of bytes that can be freely copied at whim, some special blobs might not like being moved and they will not appreciate it if you force them to.

Yes, if you are dealing with PODs, this would work with a `custom::vector`, not `std::vector` based on `std::allocator`.

There is a paper in works which addresses your concerns and goes beyond `realloc`, arguing "its day has passed" - [P0901](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p0901r9.html) which few days ago received [rather positive feedback](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/18#issuecomment-1310818023) from the committee.

Comment: Huge thanks for such detailed answer and links to additional information!